# target="_blank" is being appended to links in my facebook app when not using https

Tags: facebook, https

My app is working correctly if the user is using https. But if the user is not using https, facebook is inserting `target="_blank"` into all hyperlinks, which causes it to open a new tab outside of facebook. Why is it doing this, and what do I need to do to get it working correctly?

Comment: @AnuragShukla [http://www.facebook.com/rvwholesalers/app_415885011830355?ref=ts](http://www.facebook.com/rvwholesalers/app_415885011830355?ref=ts)

Answer (score 0):

Your Page https://secure.rvwholesalers.com/rvwholesalers/facebook/apps/inventory/ is already appending target="_blank"

```
<tr>
<td><a style="font-size: 16px;" target="_blank" href="http://www.rvwholesalers.com/rvs/sierra-376bhok-vs-sandpiper-376bhok.html">Compare our Sandpiper 376BHOK to their Sierra 376BHOK.</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The links at the bottom should be, but the links at the top should not.  this is what it should look like: `<a href="https://secure.rvwholesalers.com/rvwholesalers/facebook/apps/inventory/travel-trailers" title="Browse Travel Trailers">`, and this is what facebook is inserting `<a target="_blank" href="http://www.rvwholesalers.com/facebook/apps/inventory/travel-trailers" title="Browse Travel Trailers">`.

Comment: BTW, both domains point to the same file, so that is not a problem.